# Projective objects of chain category

Tags: category-theory, exact-sequence, abelian-categories, projective-module

I am tempted to think that the projective objects in the chain category $\text{Ch}(\mathcal C)$ for $\mathcal C$ abelian are exactly the complexes $P_\bullet$ for which each $P_i$ is projective. Is this true? If not, what is a counterexample?

Comment: This is false. For the correct statement see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/115449/projective-objects-in-the-category-of-chain-complexes.